# How to get updated document ids with bulk update in golang with Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query, mgo

I am working on a golang project. I am using MongoDB database.
I need to get the all documents ids with the bulk update function. I am using mgo golang package with the code below:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
   "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
)
type QueryStruct struct{
   Selector    bson.M
   Query       bson.M   
}

func main(){
   session, err := mgo.Dial("127.0.0.1")
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }

   defer session.Close()

   session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)
   var queries []QueryStruct
   for i:=1; i<=400; i++{
      var query QueryStruct
      query.Selector = bson.M{"country":"US"}
      query.Query = bson.M{"$set":bson.M{"serial_number":i}}
      queries = append(queries, query)
   }
   c := session.DB("test").C("people")
   bulk := c.Bulk()
   for _, queryVal := range queries{
       bulk.UpdateAll(queryVal.Selector, queryVal.Query)
   }
   data, err := bulk.Run()
   fmt.Println(data)
   fmt.Println(err)
}
```

I am getting the output like this:

```
&{117 117 false}
<nil>
```

I need to get the updated document ids to maintain the logs if any entry is not updated.

Can anybody suggest me how I can achieve this?

Comment: `UpdateAll()` operation does not return the IDs of the matched documents. If you need the IDs, you need to find another way.

Comment: @icza Is there an another way to achieve this requirement with optimized way. As I dont't want to execute the single update query within the loop.

Comment: I don't know your end goal why you need this. That might help suggesting a better solution.

Comment: @icza I need to maintain the logs like successful ids :[1,2,3,4,56,7,8,9] and unsuccessful ids:[11,23]. If I got any error during data update.

Comment: But why do you need that? If you just want to "mark" or make "searchable" the updated documents, you can set a field of them as part of the update document.

Comment: @icza  I don't want to "mark" or make "searchable" the updated documents. I need to maintain the logs, If there is an error during update then I can update that document manually. And these entities can update number of times. I have just set the test example code.

Comment: The update on a document is atomic. So if you mark them with a field, you can continue where the operation was aborted (unmarked documents). If the "marking" field bothers you, you can remove that field once all documents have been updated properly, preventing "document pollution".'

Comment: @icza I am not aware of the atomic term. Can you please elaborate your answer with example or provide any article regarding your solution. It will save my time.

Comment: When you perform an update on a document, the update document is either completely applied on the document, or it is not changed at all. E.g. if the update document tells to change 2 fields, you can be sure that either both fields will be changed, or none of them (it cannot happen that only 1 field changes).

Comment: @icza Thank you for your explanation :)